# Using TextCell in a StackLayout in a ListView

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Why can I not use a `TextCell` like this in a `ListView` item template? When I use it the rows render but they are empty.

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Courses}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextCell Text="{Binding Title}" Detail="{Binding SubTitle}"></TextCell>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

When using a `Label` I can see the text contents in each row:

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Courses}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Title}"></Label>
                        <Label Text="{Binding SubTitle}"></Label>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Is there anyway I can use the `TextCell` inside the list item template? I am trying to build a more complext layout inside the `StackLayout` and it would be greatly simplified if I could re-use the Title/Detail structure of the `TextCell`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Xamarin.Forms Cell Reference](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/controls/cells/), cells are only designed to be added to `ListViews` or `TableViews`. In particular, it says:

> However Cell is not a visual element, it just describes a template for
>   creating a visual element.

So it cannot be added directly to the children of a StackLayout. You will have to create a ViewCell with a custom template for that.. You can probably look at the source code on Github to find out the proper spacing that a TextCell uses between it's Text and TextDetail labels, to keep it consistent.

Answer (score 0):

You Can Use Stack Layout in a text cell!
Here is the way for using it.

```
   <TextCell>
      <TextCell.BindingContext>
         <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >                      
            <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
             HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="Black"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding Description}"  
             HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="Black"/>
           <Label Text="{Binding Price}"  
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="Black"/>
         </StackLayout>                       
        </TextCell.BindingContext>
       </TextCell>
```